# Apply register int in iOS

Tags: c, data-structures, arm, processor

I learned about **register**

sample:

`register int a;`

Says the compiler to use a variable faster (save my int variable in register) 
but if non have registers in processor - for my variable set **auto**

iPhone ARM processors can have this special registers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any processor has registers (except very rare and now dead stack-based architectures). The keyword `register` in C is just a hint for the compiler to map that variable in a register and not on the stack. This comes from "ancient" times when the algorithms to map variables to registers weren't that efficient. Nowadays these algorithms map better than a human could, so there is really no need to use the `register` hint.

I really don't know about iPhone ARM compilers, but I really don't think they don't use modern algorithms to map variables to registers.

Also note that what I have told you is valid for compiling with optimization flags.

---

Register are the fastest memory a processor has, it resides inside the CPU, they run at the speed of the processor and have no time penalty to access it. However, registers are limited and very few, from 4-6 general purpose registers (on CISC architectures) to 10-20 registers (on RISC architectures). A compiler will try to map the most <del>used</del> accessed variables to these registers. When he runs out of registers he has to map the variables on the stack, which is much slower (it is in RAM, but mostly it is cached in cache L1 or L2).
So the decision as which variables are mapped to registers and which variables are mapped on the stack has significant impact on performance, but, as I have said, nowadays the compilers are doing a better job than a human could at mapping variables to registers.

Comment: You believe that can not use register?

Comment: @ScarX I know that there is no need anymore to use the `register` keyword in C.

Comment: You can use it if you wish, but it unlikely to achieve anything. ARM has up to about 9 or 10 of its 16 registers available to a compiler. By default it will use registers unless it has to spill a temporary to the stack.

Comment: thanks marko and bolov

Comment: @marko That is a good point.  Ironically, I think it may change in the future.  For instance *link time optimization* will typically prevent emitting prologue/epilogue so that the registers are always under pressure.  Much like a file of many `static` functions can compile as one big function; with the compiler in-lining variables/functions.  So even though the register limit may seem big, even sane practical code could max out r4-r12.  From the LTO's point of view, maxing out the registers is optimal.

Answer (score 1):

[Bolov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2805305/bolov) provides a fairly good answer.  However, there are couple of additional points on `register`.

### No pointers

First, you may not take the address of a `register` variable.  With most compilers, the `auto` variables are tracked and annotated as being referenced by a pointer and it won't usually make a difference.  However, there may be cases where a compiler can not determine that a pointer is not *aliased* to a variable and in this case a `register` variable may actually be better.  As the variable is declared `register`, there is no way it can be aliased via a pointer.  See info on the [`restrict`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrict) keyword for more on aliasing.

Ironically, this will probably come into play with lower optimizations levels.

### Inline assembler

If you explicitly declare a register to use with *clang* or *gcc* syntax you need something like,

```
 register unsigned int *stack asm("sp");
```

`register` is needed in order to have a variable `stack` which points to the top of the stack.  This is an extension to the 'C' language, but it is relevant for iOS and its common compilers.

### Tie breaker

In an exceedingly complex algorithm, using `register` can give a hint to the compile to keep the value in memory (in favor of other variables).  Usually, like `inline`, it is better to just let the compiler decide.  Unless you have done extensive profiling and found that the compiler was saving a commonly used variable on the stack.

If you don't over use the keyword, it can also serve as documentation that the variable is performance critical; although a comment might be just as good in this case.

For the `register` keyword to make a difference on the ARM (r0-r15) you need a very complex algorithm and large function bodies.  It maybe more useful in *thumb* mode where less registers are available; For iOS ARM devices this does not apply.

Usually `register` is never needed.  It is also conceivable that over-use could actually result in **worse** performing code.  It shouldn't be an automatic reflex to add this keyword and should only be done after code is completely functional and an optimization phase has begun.

Comment: An example of the **tie breaker** is where the compiler treats all code as equal.  For instance, to minimize the time when a *mutex* is held or to calculate a hardware FIFO value in an interrupt as opposed to book keeping code in the same interrupt; the latency of parts of the routine is more important than the total run-time.  Certainly there are still some cases to use `register` even in 2014+, especially with other techniques like a [*memory barrier*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier)